# This tar command works on command line but fails in a script

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, tar

This tar command works on command line but fails in a script.

CODE:

```
find ~/ -name "sql*.db" | tar -czv -f backup.tar.gz -T -
```

OUTPUT FROM COMMAND LINE:

```
find ~/ -name "sql*.db" | tar -czv -f backup.tar.gz -T -
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/home/myuser/folder1/sql1.db
/home/myuser/folder2/sql2.db
/home/myuser/folder3/sql3.db
/home/myuser/folder4/sql4.db
/home/myuser/folder5/sql5.db
```

ERROR FROM SCRIPT:

```
[ps623237]$ sh backup.sh
tar: -\r: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what commands you are running. Please give exact list of commands, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Not to mention the potential circular-reference attempting to include the archive you are creating in the backup set.

Comment: David, could you explain the potential circular reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the Windows (CRLF) instead of the Linux (LF). I used notepad++

```
Edit/EOL Conversion/UNIX
```

to fix it. Here is the refined code.

```
#!/bin/sh
DOW=$(date +"%A");
find /home/user1 -name sql*.db | tar -czv -f /home/user1/backup/$DOW.DB.tar.gz -T -
```